# spread props in react using typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

When I first started to adapt typescript in react, I notice I can't using `...props`, as typescript check every single prop that are passed in the components. It's great but it's also annoying, where I have to pass native props like id, name etc declaratively as props.

```
interface MyComponentProps {
  name: string,
  id: string,
  placeholder: string
}

const MyComponent = ({
  name,
  id,
  placeholder
}: MyComponentProps) => {
  return <input type="text" placeholder={placeholder} name={name} id={id}/>
}
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MyComponent placeholder="Name" name="something" id="myInput" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should edit your interface such that it is extending the props of the HTML `input` element:

```
interface MyComponentProps extends InputHTMLAttributes< HTMLInputElement>)  {
  // add other custom props
}

const MyComponent: React.FC<MyComponentProps> = (props) => (...)
```

Comment: besides InputHTMLAttributes what other type are there? for `div`, `li` etc, how do I know those thing?

Comment: You can refer to this cheatsheet! https://www.saltycrane.com/cheat-sheets/typescript/react/latest/ its not that complicated once you get a hang of it

Comment: This was crazy helpful to me and I'm annoyed that you were downvoted. To future readers, I needed this for an anchor "a" link and I used `LinkHTMLAttributes` instead of `InputHTMLAttributes`. In my editor I just navigate to the file where the types are defined and they're all there with the supported attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly cast it to `HTMLAttributes`

Declare an interface like union of component's props with HTMLAttributes

```
interface MyComponentProps = {}

const MyComponent: React.FC<MyComponentProps & HTMLAttributes>...
```

Detailed explanation you can find here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40032869/4186110