# Using rest parameters when receiving component props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

How can I use rest parameters to receive extended properties in a react functional component?

This is my component:

```
import React from 'react';
import "./button.component.css"

interface IProps
{
    onClick: ()=>void,
    caption: string,
}

function ButtonComponent( {onClick, caption, ...otherProps} : IProps) {
    return (
        <button onClick={onClick} className="button" {...otherProps}>{caption}</button>
    );
};

export default ButtonComponent;
```

and I use it like this:

```
<ButtonComponent id="register" caption="CREATE ACCOUNT" style={{width:"48%", backgroundColor:"#00AAFF", color:"#FFF"}} onClick={()=>{console.log("")} }></ButtonComponent>
```

And this is giving the error:

```
TypeScript error in /Users/hexdump/Documents/Development/react/crwn-clothing/src/components/register-form/register-form.component.tsx(16,34): Type '{ id: string; caption: string; style: { width: string; backgroundColor: string; color: string; }; onClick: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IProps'.
```

Why can't I expand the properties not present in the interface in the button tag attributes?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40032592/typescript-workaround-for-rest-props-in-react is this what you looking for :D

Comment: @AnhTuan ummm, this seems a bit of a hack to me. I saw in typescript repository people has been  asking for this to be solved for years... it seems they didn't fixt it yet :P. On the other hand this is for Typescript 2.1. Things have improved a lot.

Comment: Agree but I think the main purpose of type script is 'type' . so with ...otherProps, it hard to know what kind of data store in that props :D

Answer (score 1):

Correct typing for your `ButtonComponent` is:

```typescript
function ButtonComponent( 
{onClick, caption, ...otherProps} : IProps & React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>
) {
    return (
        <button onClick={onClick} className="button" {...otherProps}>{caption}</button>
    );
};
```

`IProps` are custom user defined props and `React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>` are [correct](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/f45d5a3/types/react/v16/index.d.ts#L2038) `button`'s tag properties. `HTMLButtonElement` type inside angular brackets is type for typing [argument of event handlers](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/f45d5a3/types/react/v16/index.d.ts#L1343).

[TS playground](https://tsplay.dev/N7bMDw)

Answer (score -3):

You should send him the properties you want him to add:

```
import React from 'react';
import "./button.component.css";
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Button = styled.button`
  width:"48%", 
  backgroundColor:"#00AAFF", 
  color:"#FFF"
`;

interface IProps
{
    onClick: ()=>void,
    caption: string,
    id: int
}

function ButtonComponent( {onClick, {...otherProps} : IProps) {
    return (
        <Button onClick={onClick} {...otherProps}>{caption}</Button>
    );
};

export default ButtonComponent;
```

```
const otherProps = {
 "id":"register",
 "caption":"CREATE ACCOUNT"
};
<ButtonComponent onClick={()=>{console.log("")}} {...otherProps}></ButtonComponent>
```

I used styled-components for styles.
To install:

```
yarn add styled-components //In yarn
npm install --save styled-components //In npm
```

Comment: Exactly, this is what I don't want to do. I don't want to add every possible attribute to the ButtonComponent signature. I just want to add the onClick and caption and use the rest parameters for the rest. This is not what I'm looking for. It would work for this specific case but not the generic one where you could pass any html attribute.

Comment: You can also use it this way, you have to create a constant key => value and in the parameters add the brackets in the spread operator.

Comment: As I said before, this is not what I need. I don't want to specify every prop that I could get in the interface type.

Comment: At some point you will have to collect the parameters you need to show them in the button, when you do you add them to a variable, key => value, and you show them regardless of the number of parameters