# Spreading object in JSX looses type safety

Tags: typescript, jsx

This is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40032592/typescript-workaround-for-rest-props-in-react)

I can see that passing down non typesafe props might be useful for native HTML components, but this also apply to all other React components which I think is a problem. I sometimes use this notation when I have some variables with the same names as the props I need to pass down:

```
<MyComponent {...{ foo, bar }} />
```

because it is more terse and more easy to read than (especially when the number of props is long):

```
<MyComponent foo={foo} bar={bar} />
```

But when I use this notation I loose type safety and can add any invalid props:

```
<MyComponent {...{ foo, bar, invalidProp }} />
```

And this means that if I remove a prop from `MyComponent` I don't get a compiler error in the places where I pass it down and really shouldn't calculate it any longer.

Is there a way to turn this off for non native HTML components?

You can see an example in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-spread-props-in-jsx-tmeyun?file=/src/index.tsx:1062-1108)

Comment: TypeScript does not do excess property checks most of the times because they are not a problem in a structural type system. Can you show an example where this causes a problem for you?

Comment: The problem arises when foo is no longer a prop on MyComponent, but I still calculate it (might be expensive) and pass it down. I would like the compiler to complain when I use a prop that doesn’t exist.